# Edge Work Profile lets my boss monitor what I am doing

Tags: ms-office, microsoft-edge

I use Edge. My employer invited me to use portal.office.com.
I am alarmed to find that this converted my default Edge profile called Personal into a work profile in which my employer can see all URLs which I visit.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/discussions/edge-should-explain-the-privacy-implications-of-signing-into/m-p/1335844

I set up another profile but if I visit Skype then the tab gets moved to my Personal (work) profile.

You can specify the profile in a desktop shortcut with

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 2" www.google.com
```

However although I have three selectable profiles I only have two profile directories and changing profile in one session seems to change the profile in another session. The whole model seems to be bug ridden.

My questions are:

Is there a possibility that my employer can see everything I do with Edge regardless of which profile I am using?

Can my employer can see everything I do with Word, etc?

Can my employer see what I am doing using programs **other than** Word, Office, Edge, Skype etc?

Can my employer access my file system?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Edge by creating a new InPrivate tab.